# Building and maintaining an options array/object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a faceted/filtering search for a project I'm currently working on and I'm looking for a function (or jquery plugin) to help me do this. Let's say I have an object like the following:

```
var options = {
    "country": 2,
    "Gender": 1
}
```

I then have a function called filter(). I pass filter the key and value of the option I want to toggle/add/update. My current function is causing me nothing but trouble and I'm too far down the debugging rabbit hole to make it worth posting. Essentially I have this:

```
filter('country', 3);
```

would update the 'country' key to have '3' as its new value.

```
filter('Age Group', 4);
```

would add that key/value pair to the options object.

```
filter('Gender', 1);
```

would remove the 'Gender' key from the object completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this obvious implementation:

```
​function filter(o, key, val)​ {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(key) && o[key] == val) {
        delete o[key];    
    } else {
        o[key] = val;
    }
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this:

```
​function filter(o, key, val)​ {
    if (o[key] === val) {
        delete o[key];    
    } else {
        o[key] = val;
    }
}
```

If the `key` does not exist as a property of the object, then `o[key]` will be `undefined` which will not match `val` so it will add the key/value.

If the `key` exists, but the `val` does not match, it will set the key/value

If the `key` exists and the `val` matches, it will remove the key.

Note: it's important to use `===` to make sure there's no auto-type conversion in the comparison.

---

Or, if you want a function that automatically works with your `options` variable, then you could use this:

```
​function filter(key, val)​ {
    if (options[key] === val) {
        delete options[key];    
    } else {
        options[key] = val;
    }
}
```

Personally, I think code is more readable if you make explicit setKey and removeKey functions rather than this variable operation based on whether the key previously exists or whether it matches.